# TypeConverter cannot convert from some base types to same base types

Tags: c#, type-conversion

Why those return `true`:

```
  TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(double)).CanConvertTo(typeof(double));
  TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(int)).CanConvertTo(typeof(int));
```

when those return `false`?

```
  TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(decimal)).CanConvertTo(typeof(decimal));
  TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(bool)).CanConvertTo(typeof(bool));
```

Event considering that all the converters returned by GetConverter are supposed to only convert the types to and from a string :

- [DoubleConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.doubleconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Int32Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.int32converter(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [DecimalConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.decimalconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [BooleanConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.booleanconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)

I'm using .NET Framework 4.5.2.

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone, other than a member of the BCL team, can really explain if there was an actual reason for this, or if it was just an oversight. I do see logic in [BaseNumberConverter.CanConvertTo](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/R/0ca895b4d1e6191c.html) that checks for primitive types, which Decimal is *not*, thus explaining the discrepancy with Decimal. But why not support Decimal as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DecimalConverter` (as well as `DoubleConverter` and `Int32Converter`) overrides `CanConvertTo` to indicate it can convert to strings (because that's what `base.CanConvertTo` does) *and all CLR primitive types*.  From [the Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/compmod/system/componentmodel/basenumberconverter.cs.html#0ca895b4d1e6191c):

```
public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type t) 
{
    if (base.CanConvertTo(context, t) || t.IsPrimitive) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

`decimal` is NOT a primitive type from the CLR's perspective, so the converter returns `false` when passed `typeof(decimal)`.

`BooleanConverter` does not override `CanConvertTo`, so it falls to the base implementation which only allows a conversion to `string`:

```
public virtual bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType) 
{
    return (destinationType == typeof(string));
}
```

If you're asking *why it's designed that way*, then only the Framework designers can say, but I suspect it's because it's a trivial check to see if you're trying to convert from one type to the same type.

Considering that their purpose is to convert non-string types to/from strings for displaying in property grids, XAML, etc., it's not surprising that it doesn't fully support non-string conversions.

Comment: Isn't bool a primitive type? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx

Comment: I just checked with Reflection, typeof(bool).IsPrimative is true, so I don't no what "bool are NOT primative types from the CLR's perspective means".

Comment: @DanielGimenez I was incorrect.  Interestingly, that means `DecimalConverter.CanConvertTo(typeof(bool))` returns true, which makes no sense.  It seems to convert 0 to `false` and anything else to `true` like C++ does.

Comment: I just don't think anybody thought of this before @Matthieu.  Why you can't convert bool to a numeric, when you can convert numerics to bool seems like an oversight.

Comment: @DanielGimenez I doubt converting numbers to bools was part of the original design - the purpose was to be able to convert values to strings (for displaying in property boxes and embedding in markup) and parsing from strings (when settings are changed in the property grid or markup).  Also since it's not reversible (how do you convert true to 4?) it makes sense not to allow it.

Answer (score 8):

`Boolean`, `Char`, `DateTime`, `String` and `Object`'s `TypeConverter` inherit from `BaseTypeConverter` and don't overwrite `CanConvertTo`, which return true only if the type passed is of type `string`.  That is why `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(bool)).CanConvertTo(typeof(bool))` is false.

The type converters for `Byte`, `Double`, `Int16`, `Int32`, `Int64`, `SByte`, `Single`, `UInt16`, `UInt32`, and `UInt64` are all derived from `BaseNumberConverter` which returns true for `CanCovertTo` for types that are strings or primitive types.

`Decimal` does inherit from `BaseNumberConverter` as well, but since it's not a primitive, passing decimal type to `CanConvertTo` will result in false.  That is why `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(decimal)).CanConvertTo(typeof(decimal))` is false.

Here's a full chart for the results of `CanConvertTo`:

```
FROM/TO     Bol Byt Chr DTm Dec Dbl I16 I32 I64 SBt Sng Str Obj U16 U32 U64
Boolean                                                 +               
Byte        +   +   +           +   +   +   +   +   +   +       +   +   +
Char                                                    +               
DateTime                                                +               
Decimal     +   +   +           +   +   +   +   +   +   +       +   +   +
Double      +   +   +           +   +   +   +   +   +   +       +   +   +
Int16       +   +   +           +   +   +   +   +   +   +       +   +   +
Int32       +   +   +           +   +   +   +   +   +   +       +   +   +
Int64       +   +   +           +   +   +   +   +   +   +       +   +   +
SByte       +   +   +           +   +   +   +   +   +   +       +   +   +
Single      +   +   +           +   +   +   +   +   +   +       +   +   +
String                                                  +               
Object                                                  +               
UInt16      +   +   +           +   +   +   +   +   +   +       +   +   +
UInt32      +   +   +           +   +   +   +   +   +   +       +   +   +
UInt64      +   +   +           +   +   +   +   +   +   +       +   +   +
```

Types and their converters:

```
Type        Converter class     Converter inherits from
----------  ------------------  -----------------------
Boolean     BooleanConverter    TypeConverter
Byte        ByteConverter       BaseNumberConverter
Char        CharConverter       TypeConverter
DateTime    DateTimeConverter   TypeConverter
Decimal     DecimalConverter    BaseNumberConverter
Double      DoubleConverter     BaseNumberConverter
Int16       Int16Converter      BaseNumberConverter
Int32       Int32Converter      BaseNumberConverter
Int64       Int64Converter      BaseNumberConverter
SByte       SByteConverter      BaseNumberConverter
Single      SingleConverter     BaseNumberConverter
String      StringConverter     TypeConverter
Object      TypeConverter       Object
UInt16      UInt16Converter     BaseNumberConverter
UInt32      UInt32Converter     BaseNumberConverter
UInt64      UInt64Converter     BaseNumberConverter
UInt32      UInt32Converter     BaseNumberConverter
UInt64      UInt64Converter     BaseNumberConverter
```